# How to create reusable function to lower-camel-case text?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to create a function that lower-camel-cases any text that I happen to select, whether the plain text value of a node ("UserRole") or the value of an attribute ("UserRoleInfo"). Here's sample data:

```
<className>UserRole</className>         <!-- Want to create text userRole -->

<fieldGroups>
    <fieldGroup name="UserRoleInfo"/>   <!-- Want to create text userRoleInfo -->
</fieldGroups>
```

No need to read any further if you would like to provide a solution.  But here is my attempt to implement such a thing if you are interested.

Here, I'm selecting the className:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="lowerCaseName" select="/className"/>
```

Here, I'm selecting the attribute:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="printFieldGroupAssignments" select="/fieldGroups"/>

<xsl:template mode="printFieldGroupAssignments" match="fieldGroups">
    <xsl:for-each select="./fieldGroup">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="lowerCaseName" select="./attribute::name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

So here is my "reusable function" that should accept either a node or an attribute.

```
<xsl:template mode="lowerCaseName" match="node()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(lower-case(substring(.,1,1)), substring(.,2))"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="lowerCaseName" match="attribute()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(lower-case(substring(.,1,1)), substring(.,2))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I get the following error:

> [ERROR]: Syntax error in 'attribute()'.
>
> [ERROR]: file:Entity.xsl: line 849: Error parsing XPath expression 'attribute()'.

So I change attribute() to text()

```
<xsl:template mode="lowerCaseName" match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(lower-case(substring(.,1,1)), substring(.,2))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I get the following error:

> [ERROR]: Could not compile stylesheet
>
> [FATAL]: Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(lower-case, [funcall(substring, [cast(variable-ref(entityClassName/node-set), string), cast(int-expr(1), real), cast(int-expr(1), real)])])'.

I think my problem is that I'm not understanding the difference between nodes, node-sets, and just plain old text.

What should be my next step to fix this?  Should I discard and start over with a different approach?  All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

> I think my problem is that I'm not understanding the difference
>   between nodes, node-sets, and just plain old text.

Those are important distinctions. IMHO, there are two more which may be more pertinent here: (1) function vs. named template and (2) apply templates vs. call template.

Re #1, you say you want to create a function, but you are writing templates.
Re #2, you are applying templates using *mode*, where you should be calling a *named template*.

To do this with a named template, you would define a template such as:

```
<xsl:template name="lowerFirst">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(lower-case(substring($text, 1, 1)), substring($text, 2))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

then call it as necessary. For example, given the following **test input**:

```
<root>
    <anything>AnyThing</anything>
    <!-- leave as is -->

    <className name="TestCase">UserRole</className>
    <!-- Want to create text userRole -->

    <fieldGroups>
        <fieldGroup name="UserRoleInfo"/>
        <!-- Want to create text userRoleInfo -->
    </fieldGroups>
</root>
```

you could use the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="lowerFirst">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(lower-case(substring($text, 1, 1)), substring($text, 2))"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="className">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="lowerFirst">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fieldGroup/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:call-template name="lowerFirst">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
      <anything>AnyThing</anything>
   <!-- leave as is -->

    <className name="TestCase">userRole</className>
   <!-- Want to create text userRole -->

    <fieldGroups>
            <fieldGroup name="userRoleInfo"/>
      <!-- Want to create text userRoleInfo -->
    </fieldGroups>
</root>
```

--
In XSLT 2.0, you can create your own function and use it instead of a named template, for example:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="my:lowerFirst">
    <xsl:param name="text"/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(lower-case(substring($text, 1, 1)), substring($text, 2))"/>
</xsl:function>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="className">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="my:lowerFirst(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fieldGroup/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="my:lowerFirst(.)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT 2.0 allows writing `<xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="my:lowerFirst(.)"/></xsl:attribute>` as `<xsl:attribute name="name" select="my:lowerFirst(.)"/>`.

Comment: @michael the output of both of your examples is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>AnyThing<!-- leave as is --><classname xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="TestCase">userRole</classname><!-- Want to create text userRole --><!-- Want to create text userRoleInfo -->` according to [XSLT Fiddle](http://fiddle.frameless.io/).  I don't see it transforming UserRoleInfo.  It's not producing the output that you list, above.

Comment: @michael `xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"` gives the error that "URI is not registered" and it's telling me to add the schema or DTD.

Comment: @michael what does `exclude-result-prefixes="my"` do?

Comment: @PatrickGarner It seems that the "Frameless" processor at XSLT Fiddle is not functioning properly. Try it with Saxon, available both there and at: http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have written match="attribute()". If you want to match any attribute, the usual way is `match="@*"`, but you can also (in 2.0) write `match="attribute(*)"` if you prefer. As the error message indicates, your syntax isn't allowed.

This is just a minor addition to the good answers that others have given you.

Comment: This is very helpful.  `xsl:version` shows 1.0.  Using `saxon9he.jar` gives the output 2.0.  So, now, can use `match="attribute()"`.

Comment: I've just realised that my code wasn't marked up properly and the asterisk wasn't showing, although it was there - sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Is the asterisk in `attribute(*)` required?  Where do you go online to look at reference material?  I've not been impressed w/ W3Schools and MDN seems to be focused mainly on JS and DOM.

Comment: I apologize, I'm wrong: the asterisk is optional. I was thinking of function(*), where it is required. The definitive XPath grammar is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#nt-bnf, and the relevant production is `[60] AttributeTest ::= "attribute" "("(AttribNameOrWildcard ("," TypeName)?)? ")"`